# Three js - WaterShader horizontal plane (rotation of mesh ?)

Tags: three.js

I'm new here, and happy to find such a good forum :)

In Three JS, I'm trying to have some water plane horizontal. I could insert the water plane working properly if vertical (rotation on X axis), but when I place it horizontal the textures turn very bad.
Here is my code :

```
var light = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffbb, 1 );
light.position.set( - 1, 1, - 1 );
scene.add( light );

waterNormals = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'editor/textures/waternormals.jpg' );
waterNormals.wrapS = waterNormals.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

water = new THREE.Water( webGLRenderer, camera, scene, {
    textureWidth: 512,
    textureHeight: 512,
    waterNormals: waterNormals,
    alpha:  0.7,
    sunDirection: light.position.clone().normalize(),
    sunColor: 0xffffff,
    waterColor: 0x001e0f,
    distortionScale: 50.0,
    fog: scene.fog != undefined
} );

var WaterGeometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( parameters.width * 500, parameters.height * 500 );
// WaterGeometry.rotateX( Math.PI / 2 );

var mirrorMesh = new THREE.Mesh(WaterGeometry, water.material);

mirrorMesh.add( water );
mirrorMesh.position.set(0, -200, 200);
mirrorMesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI * 0.5;
scene.add( mirrorMesh );
```

Here is the result: Good texture but vertical plane
[image: Good texture but vertical plane]

When I remove the line:

```
mirrorMesh.rotation.x = - Math.PI * 0.5;
```

The new result is: Bad texture but horizontal plane
[image: Bad texture but horizontal plane]

Any idea of what is happenning ?

Thank you !

Comment: Hi "Salut", any change if you add with and height segments, PlaneBufferGeometry(width, height, widthSegments, heightSegments); for example try with a 3th param as "40" and if the rendering the rotation situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to add shaders and create you own sea i add timer to make the cinematics, look at lighting and try to used like this, regards.

```js
// init camera, scene, renderer
var scene, camera, renderer;
scene = new THREE.Scene();
var fov = 75,
  aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 100;
camera.lookAt(scene.position);
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setClearColor(0xc4c4c4);
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var clock = new THREE.Clock();

var tuniform = {
 iGlobalTime: {
  type: 'f',
  value: 0.1
 },
 iResolution: {
  type: 'v2',
  value: new THREE.Vector2()
 },
 iMouse: {
  type: 'v4',
  value: new THREE.Vector2()
 }
};

// Mouse position in - 1 to 1
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
 var canvas = renderer.domElement;
 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 tuniform.iMouse.value.x = (e.clientX - rect.left) / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;
 tuniform.iMouse.value.y = (e.clientY - rect.top) / window.innerHeight * -2 + 1; 
});
renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
 var canvas = renderer.domElement;
 var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
 tuniform.iMouse.value.z = (e.clientX - rect.left) / window.innerWidth * 2 - 1;
 tuniform.iMouse.value.w = (e.clientY - rect.top) / window.innerHeight * -2 + 1;
});
// resize canvas function
window.addEventListener('resize',function() {
 camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
 renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
});

tuniform.iResolution.value.x = window.innerWidth;
tuniform.iResolution.value.y = window.innerHeight;
// Create Plane
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
 uniforms: tuniform,
 vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
 fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
 new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight, 40), material
);
scene.add(mesh);

// draw animation
function render(time) {
 tuniform.iGlobalTime.value += clock.getDelta();
 requestAnimationFrame(render);
 renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
render();
```

```css
body {
 overflow: hidden;
 margin: 0;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.min.js"></script>

<!-- THIS is OPENGL Shading language scripts -->
<script id="vertex-shader" type="no-js">
  void main() {
   gl_Position = vec4( position, 1.0 );
  }
</script>

<script id="fragment-shader" type="no-js">
 uniform float iGlobalTime;
 uniform vec2 iResolution;
 uniform vec4 iMouse;
 
const int NUM_STEPS = 8;
const float PI   = 3.1415;
const float EPSILON = 1e-3;
float EPSILON_NRM = 0.1 / iResolution.x;

// sea
const int ITER_GEOMETRY = 3;
const int ITER_FRAGMENT = 5;
const float SEA_HEIGHT = 0.6;
const float SEA_CHOPPY = 4.0;
const float SEA_SPEED = 0.8;
const float SEA_FREQ = 0.16;
//coloration sea
const vec3 SEA_BASE = vec3(0.1,0.19,0.22);
const vec3 SEA_WATER_COLOR = vec3(0.8,0.9,0.6);
float SEA_TIME = iGlobalTime * SEA_SPEED;
mat2 octave_m = mat2(1.6,1.2,-1.2,1.6);

// math
mat3 fromEuler(vec3 ang) {
 vec2 a1 = vec2(sin(ang.x),cos(ang.x));
    vec2 a2 = vec2(sin(ang.y),cos(ang.y));
    vec2 a3 = vec2(sin(ang.z),cos(ang.z));
    mat3 m;
    m[0] = vec3(a1.y*a3.y+a1.x*a2.x*a3.x,a1.y*a2.x*a3.x+a3.y*a1.x,-a2.y*a3.x);
 m[1] = vec3(-a2.y*a1.x,a1.y*a2.y,a2.x);
 m[2] = vec3(a3.y*a1.x*a2.x+a1.y*a3.x,a1.x*a3.x-a1.y*a3.y*a2.x,a2.y*a3.y);
 return m;
}
float hash( vec2 p ) {
 float h = dot(p,vec2(127.1,311.7)); 
    return fract(sin(h)*43758.5453123);
}
float noise( in vec2 p ) {
    vec2 i = floor( p );
    vec2 f = fract( p ); 
 vec2 u = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
    return -1.0+2.0*mix( mix( hash( i + vec2(0.0,0.0) ), 
                     hash( i + vec2(1.0,0.0) ), u.x),
                mix( hash( i + vec2(0.0,1.0) ), 
                     hash( i + vec2(1.0,1.0) ), u.x), u.y);
}

// lighting
float diffuse(vec3 n,vec3 l,float p) {
    return pow(dot(n,l) * 0.4 + 0.6,p);
}
float specular(vec3 n,vec3 l,vec3 e,float s) {    
    float nrm = (s + 8.0) / (3.1415 * 8.0);
    return pow(max(dot(reflect(e,n),l),0.0),s) * nrm;
}

// sky
vec3 getSkyColor(vec3 e) {
    e.y = max(e.y,0.0);
    vec3 ret;
    ret.x = pow(1.0-e.y,2.0);
    ret.y = 1.0-e.y;
    ret.z = 0.6+(1.0-e.y)*0.4;
    return ret;
}

// sea
float sea_octave(vec2 uv, float choppy) {
    uv += noise(uv);        
    vec2 wv = 1.0-abs(sin(uv));
    vec2 swv = abs(cos(uv));    
    wv = mix(wv,swv,wv);
    return pow(1.0-pow(wv.x * wv.y,0.65),choppy);
}

float map(vec3 p) {
    float freq = SEA_FREQ;
    float amp = SEA_HEIGHT;
    float choppy = SEA_CHOPPY;
    vec2 uv = p.xz; uv.x *= 0.75;
    
    float d, h = 0.0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < ITER_GEOMETRY; i++) {        
     d = sea_octave((uv+SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
     d += sea_octave((uv-SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
        h += d * amp;        
     uv *= octave_m; freq *= 1.9; amp *= 0.22;
        choppy = mix(choppy,1.0,0.2);
    }
    return p.y - h;
}

float map_detailed(vec3 p) {
    float freq = SEA_FREQ;
    float amp = SEA_HEIGHT;
    float choppy = SEA_CHOPPY;
    vec2 uv = p.xz; uv.x *= 0.75;
    
    float d, h = 0.0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < ITER_FRAGMENT; i++) {        
     d = sea_octave((uv+SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
     d += sea_octave((uv-SEA_TIME)*freq,choppy);
        h += d * amp;        
     uv *= octave_m; freq *= 1.9; amp *= 0.22;
        choppy = mix(choppy,1.0,0.2);
    }
    return p.y - h;
}

vec3 getSeaColor(vec3 p, vec3 n, vec3 l, vec3 eye, vec3 dist) {  
    float fresnel = 1.0 - max(dot(n,-eye),0.0);
    fresnel = pow(fresnel,3.0) * 0.65;
        
    vec3 reflected = getSkyColor(reflect(eye,n));    
    vec3 refracted = SEA_BASE + diffuse(n,l,80.0) * SEA_WATER_COLOR * 0.12; 
    
    vec3 color = mix(refracted,reflected,fresnel);
    
    float atten = max(1.0 - dot(dist,dist) * 0.001, 0.0);
    color += SEA_WATER_COLOR * (p.y - SEA_HEIGHT) * 0.18 * atten;
    
    color += vec3(specular(n,l,eye,60.0));
    
    return color;
}

// tracing
vec3 getNormal(vec3 p, float eps) {
    vec3 n;
    n.y = map_detailed(p);    
    n.x = map_detailed(vec3(p.x+eps,p.y,p.z)) - n.y;
    n.z = map_detailed(vec3(p.x,p.y,p.z+eps)) - n.y;
    n.y = eps;
    return normalize(n);
}

float heightMapTracing(vec3 ori, vec3 dir, out vec3 p) {  
    float tm = 0.0;
    float tx = 1000.0;    
    float hx = map(ori + dir * tx);
    if(hx > 0.0) return tx;   
    float hm = map(ori + dir * tm);    
    float tmid = 0.0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STEPS; i++) {
        tmid = mix(tm,tx, hm/(hm-hx));                   
        p = ori + dir * tmid;                   
     float hmid = map(p);
  if(hmid < 0.0) {
         tx = tmid;
            hx = hmid;
        } else {
            tm = tmid;
            hm = hmid;
        }
    }
    return tmid;
}

void main() {
 vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    uv = uv * 2.0 - 1.0;
    uv.x *= iResolution.x / iResolution.y;    
    float time = iGlobalTime * 0.3 + iMouse.x*0.01;
        
    // ray
    vec3 ang = vec3(sin(time*3.0)*0.1,sin(time)*0.2+0.3,time);    
    vec3 ori = vec3(0.0,3.5,time*5.0);
    vec3 dir = normalize(vec3(uv.xy,-2.0)); dir.z += length(uv) * 0.15;
    dir = normalize(dir) * fromEuler(ang);
    
    // tracing
    vec3 p;
    heightMapTracing(ori,dir,p);
    vec3 dist = p - ori;
    vec3 n = getNormal(p, dot(dist,dist) * EPSILON_NRM);
    vec3 light = normalize(vec3(0.0,1.0,0.8)); 
             
    // color
    vec3 color = mix(
        getSkyColor(dir),
        getSeaColor(p,n,light,dir,dist),
     pow(smoothstep(0.0,-0.05,dir.y),0.3));
        
    // post
 gl_FragColor = vec4(pow(color,vec3(0.75)), 1.0);
 }
</script>
```

Comment: Great Thank you ! I could insert the code in my scene, it's working but I don't see the others elements anymore (meshes, ground etc)... How can I stop the movement of camera and why did the others meshes disapeared ?

Comment: @Pierre-Emmanuel Lépicier We need to talk in the chat ;) to close the post as resolved and let we talk there ;). regards then you can talk in french if you wanted.

Comment: Ok to jump to the chat room we need to comment more, i think your status level can't take you there cos you need some new privilege depend on score.

Comment: try to full the comment ;)

Comment: do you use skype?